# mobile app with friend group

Tags: mobile, cordova, extjs

I want to create two flavors of a mobile app.
In Full version, the user can invite friends to join his group and then once the friend accepts the invite, the friend will be able to download the lighter flavor of the app.
In the future, the Full version app user can send notifications to the friends and friends can reply back.

There has to be some services that have already made this inviting friends and creating friend groups.  I looked up couple of platforms - Buddy (http://buddy.com) and Sencha.io (http://www.sencha.com/products/io/)

Any other recommendations on how to easily go about making this kind of app?
I prefer making this app in HTML5 (maybe using PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile) to make it cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

In my own experience:

- JQM & PG work well (enough) for some kind of apps.
- Sencha is painful to use.
- For notifications, use Urban Airship.

I could give more advice, but you didn't say what your app will do.

Answer (score 0):

Using Buddy Services for accomplishing the task